# Running javascript if statement is true otherwise do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen

```
function loadMenus() {
    if(w <= 767){
        $(".history").click(function(){
            $(".historyMenu").slideToggle("fast");
        });
    }
    else (w >= 768) {
        // Do not load 
    }
}
```

Im trying to run a slide toggle only when the size of the window is less than 767 but do nothing when is greater than that. I only want a specific functionality when the window is small but not when the window is large. Help.

Comment: Just remove the `else` part?

Comment: Remove the `else` part - It's done :)

Comment: Or change ```else``` to ```else if``` if you have actual code within that block. Better yet keep ```else``` and remove ```(w >= 768)```.

Comment: It work without the else. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".history").click(function(){
             if(w <= 767) $(".historyMenu").slideToggle("fast");
});
```